# Intersection with Vitali Set not measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This is Exercise 1.16 from the Book: Mathematics++: Selected topics beyond the basic courses by Kantor, Matousek and Samal.

Prove that if $E \subseteq [0,1]$ is measurable with $\lambda(E) > 0$, then $E\cap V$ is not measurable, where $V$ is the Vitali set.

I assume one has to show that
$$
\lambda(A) \not = \lambda(A \cap E\cap V) + \lambda(A\cap(E\cap V)^c)
$$
for an arbitrary subset $A \subset \mathbb R$ but fail to do so.

How does one prove the statement?

Comment: The statement should be like this. If $X$ is a measurable set, then for every measurable set $A$ $$\lambda (A) = \lambda (A\cap X) + \lambda (A\cap X^c) $$ So if you find a measurable set $A$ for which this equality fails, that automatically forces $X$ to be non-measurable.

Comment: The text says its for every set $A\subset \mathbb R$? I was thinking of using $E$ as $A$ but did not see the contradiction.

Comment: I don't see it happening, either. $\lambda$ can measure measurable sets.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $V$ is the disjoint union of its rational translates mod $1$.  A measurable set
of positive measure can't be disjoint from all its rational translates.

Comment: So this tells us that $E \cap V$ is nonempty - but what does it say about its measure?

Comment: $E \cap V$ must also be disjoint from its rational translates.